# Possible to have Communities Header Image change based on user profile?

Tags: community

I'm on a project to create our company's employee intranet and have a branding inquiry. Without having to create communities for each division (total of 3 divisions for now), I'd like to know if there is any way to swap either the company logo and/or the header image based on the end-user's profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of winter'17, Not possible Out of the box. But you could have a custom theme layout built for a community that could change the logo based on logged in user profile.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm

Theme Layout is a lightning component and you can call apex to find out image to use based on user profile.

Images can either be stored in documents or site.com assets.

Comment: Thank you, @Sri. I suspected this was the only solution. Thanks for verifying!